# Bidirectional Dijkstra d-ary heap

Tags: algorithm, perl, heap, priority-queue

This is my very first data structure written in Perl for a [d-ary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-ary_heap):

```
package BidirectionalDijkstra::DaryHeap;

use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX;

require Exporter;

our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our $MAXIMUM_INT = 1000 * 1000 * 1000;

# Items to export into callers namespace by default. Note: do not export
# names by default without a very good reason. Use EXPORT_OK instead.
# Do not simply export all your public functions/methods/constants.

# This allows declaration   use BidirectionalDijkstra::Graph ':all';
# If you do not need this, moving things directly into @EXPORT or @EXPORT_OK
# will save memory.
our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( 'all' => [ qw(
    
) ] );

our @EXPORT_OK = ( @{ $EXPORT_TAGS{'all'} } );

our @EXPORT = qw(
    
);

our $VERSION = '1.6';

# Preloaded methods go here.

sub new($$) {
    my $class = shift;
    my $degree = shift;
    my $self = {
        node_map             => {},
        node_array           => [],
        degree               => $degree,
        children_index_array => []
    };
    bless ($self, $class);
    return $self;
}

sub get_parent_index {
    my $self = shift;
    my $index = shift;
    return floor(($index - 1) / $self->{degree});
}

sub sift_up {
    my $self = shift;
    my $index = shift;
    
    return if $index == 0;

    my $parent_index = $self->get_parent_index($index);
    my $target_node = $self->{node_array}->[$index];

    while (1) {
        my $parent_node = $self->{node_array}->[$parent_index];
        
        if ($parent_node->{priority} > $target_node->{priority}) {
            $self->{node_array}->[$index] = $parent_node;
            $parent_node->{node_index} = $index;
            $index = $parent_index;
            $parent_index = $self->get_parent_index($index);
        } else {
            last;
        }

        last if $index == 0;
    }

    $self->{node_array}->[$index] = $target_node;
    $target_node->{node_index} = $index;    
}

sub compute_children_indices {
    my $self = shift;
    my $index = shift;
    my $degree = $self->{degree};

    for my $i (0 .. $degree - 1) {
        $self->{children_index_array}->[$i] = 
            $degree * $index + $i + 1;

        if ($self->{children_index_array}
             ->[$i] >= $self->size()) {

            $self->{children_index_array}->[$i] = 
                $MAXIMUM_INT;
                
            return;
        }       
    }
}

sub sift_down_root {
    my $self = shift;

    # Nothing to sift down:
    return if $self->size() == 0;

    my $target = $self->{node_array}->[0];
    my $priority = $target->{priority};
    my $min_child_priority;
    my $tentative_priority;
    my $min_child_index;
    my $i;
    my $degree = $self->{degree};
    my $index = 0;

    while (1) {
        $min_child_priority = $priority;
        $min_child_index = $MAXIMUM_INT;
        $self->compute_children_indices($index);

        for my $i (0 .. $degree - 1) {
            if ($self->{children_index_array}->[$i] == $MAXIMUM_INT) {
                last;
            }

            $tentative_priority = 
                $self->{node_array}
                     ->[$self->{children_index_array}
                             ->[$i]]
                             ->{priority};

            if ($min_child_priority > $tentative_priority) {
                $min_child_priority = $tentative_priority;
                $min_child_index = 
                    $self->{children_index_array}
                         ->[$i];
            }
        }

        if ($min_child_index == $MAXIMUM_INT) {
            $self->{node_array}->[$index] = $target;
            $target->{node_index} = $index;
            return;
        }

        $self->{node_array}->[$index] = 
            $self->{node_array}
                 ->[$min_child_index];

        $self->{node_array}
             ->[$index]
             ->{node_index} = $index;

        $index = $min_child_index;
    }
}

sub add {
    my $self = shift;
    my $vertex = shift;
    my $priority = shift;   
    my $size = scalar @{$self->{node_array}};
    
    return if exists $self->{node_map}->{$vertex};

    my $node = {
        vertex_id  => $vertex,
        priority   => $priority,
        node_index => $size
    };

    $self->{node_array}->[$size] = $node;
    $self->{node_map}->{$vertex} = $node;
    $self->sift_up($size);
}

sub decreasePriority {
    my $self = shift;
    my $vertex = shift;
    my $priority = shift;
    my $node = $self->{node_map}->{$vertex};

    return if not exists $self->{node_map}->{$vertex};
    return if $priority >= $node->{priority};

    $node->{priority} = $priority;
    $self->sift_up($node->{node_index});
}

sub size {
    my $self = shift;
    my $size = @{$self->{node_array}};
    return $size;
}

sub extractMinimum {    
    my $self = shift;
    my $node = $self->{node_array}->[0];
    my $vertex = $node->{vertex_id};

    return undef if not exists $node->{vertex_id};
    
    $self->{node_array}->[0] = $self->{node_array}->[$self->size() - 1];
    delete $self->{node_map}->{$node->{vertex_id}};
    pop @{$self->{node_array}};
    $self->sift_down_root();
    
    return $vertex;
}

1;
```

**Critique request**

Please tell me anything that comes to mind.

**Running instructions**

The Perl module project lives [here](https://github.com/coderodde/BidirectionalDijkstra-Graph/tree/800d5a47b081797c2fd9f1e9b9cf81150a243389). Clone it, say, to `BDG`. From `BDG`, `cd` to `BidirectionalDijkstra-Graph`. From there, run this:

```
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
```

You should see `Result: PASS` at the bottom of the output.

If you want to run a simple demo, from `BDG`, run `./dary_heap_demo.pl`

Answer (score 2):

### Overview

It is great that you:

- Used `strict` and `warnings`
- Leveraged other people's code by using the `POSIX` module
- Used meaningful names for functions and variables

Here are some other adjustments for you to consider, mainly for coding style.

### Namespace

It is best to import only what is needed to avoid namespace pollution.
For example, change:

```
use POSIX;
```

to:

```
use POSIX qw(floor);
```

I use this script to identify imported functions:
[which module exports are used?](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1054312)

### Unused code

Since you only provided an OOP interface, there is no need for the
`Exporter` module or `EXPORT*` variables.

### Comments

If you do decide to keep the exporter code, the comments are not needed.
They just describe exporter usage, which users can look up in the exporter
documentation.

### Documentation

You should add a summary of the purpose of the code as well as
descriptions for the methods.
The standard way to document a module is to use plain old documentation
([POD](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod)).

Refer to [perlmodstyle](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodstyle#POD) for the
recommended sections:

- NAME
- SYNOPSIS
- DESCRIPTION
- One or more sections or subsections giving greater detail of available methods and routines and any other relevant information.
- etc.

### Linting

[perlcritic](https://metacpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/view/bin/perlcritic)
identifies some issues.

Trailing whitespace is unnecessary and can be annoying.  It should be removed.
Refer to
[Perl::Critic::Policy::CodeLayout::ProhibitTrailingWhitespace](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::CodeLayout::ProhibitTrailingWhitespace)

[Perl::Critic::Policy::Subroutines::ProhibitSubroutinePrototypes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::Subroutines::ProhibitSubroutinePrototypes)
Change:

```
sub new($$) {
```

to:

```
sub new {
```

Consider this also:
[Perl::Critic::Policy::Subroutines::RequireFinalReturn](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::Subroutines::RequireFinalReturn)